# Bizarre behaviour of letters resizing automatically as I type in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, typography, typesetting, typefaces

hoping someone can shed some light on my situation.

I am facing something I have never faced before. As I type in a text box, no matter the font, there seems to be some kind of behavioral rule telling the font to shrink ever so slightly. It only does this to characters an x amount of characters behind the character currently being typed.

Here is a gif showing what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge7dK.jpg

This happens with various fonts using this paragraph style, and does not happen using the basic paragraph style or in other documents. So I am pretty sure it is due to something in the paragraph style or character style, but I am not sure what it is. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

This is in a book document, with various paragraph styles and character styles used, some of which include GREP styles for tidying up word widows. I am using InDesign CS6.

Comment: Would appear to be some sort of screen preview update.

Comment: But in the same document with a different paragraph style it doesn't occur...

Comment: Font conflict maybe? Two similarly named fonts from different foundries? -- Just guessing really.

Comment: Make sure you clear any paragraph overrides and try again. Otherwise, possible graphics card driver issue. Try different preview options in ID.

Comment: Maybe check this isn't just some kind of on-screen display/rendering glitch. Are the letters actually changing point size?  Maybe select them and check. If not then it's probably some kind of display glitch/bug, and not something we can help with really, other than maybe suggest you make sure your graphics card driver is up-to-date.

Comment: "for tidying up word widows" - do you mean Microsoft Word?  What happens if you remove the GREP?  Since you're not typing it in Word, then it probably serves no useful purpose.

Comment: What happens if you zoom it like, really hard ? Still getting that ?

Comment: I think I tracked down the problem but I don't know exactly how to solve it - the paragraph style actually has a Grep style about runts from creativepro's article here:  https://creativepro.com/de-runt-your-paragraphs-with-a-grep-style/
If I take it out, the problem goes away. If I change the 10 to 5, for example, the shrinkage of letters begins 5 characters instead of 10 behind the last character. So is the GREP code bad? Why is this behaviour happening?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the answer has been revealed.

The character style, in advanced character controls, was for some reason set to 106% vertical scaling.

Credit to Uwe Laubender on the [Adobe forums](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/strange-font-behaviour-automatically-resizing-as-i-type/m-p/11800446?page=1) for suggesting checking that.